# \def and \edef: Expansion for one level, not more

Tags: macros, expansion, def

I want to save the content of a macro (which may contain text and other macros) for later use and without full expansion.

```
\def\mcr{a}
\def\textandmacro{sampletext \mcr} % this content i want to recall later with unexpanded \mcr
\def\save{\textandmacro}           % so i save it
\def\mcr{b}                        % the macro may change
\def\textandmacro{xy}              % this macro may change, too
%
\save                              % use '\save' here as if to type 'sampletext \mcr'
```

After that, when i use `\save` i want to get `sampletext b`, which is `sampletext` and the current meaning of `\mcr`.

But what i get is `xy` of course, because `\textandmacro` has changed.

When i `\edef` the macro `\save`, i will get `sampletext a`, because `\mcr`is fully expanded while edef-ing. This is not what i want.

What i want is some kind of an expansion for one level, not more. I don't want to save `\textandmacro` but `sampletext \mcr`.

Any ideas?

I'm working in TeX (LuaTeX), so Latex will not help me.

Best regards, Peter

Edit: the accepted answer is cool. I solved my problem with the \toks version. The other answers with the \let seem to be also right and simpler. I did't test it yet, but they are cool answers, too!

So: thank you all!

Comment: I guess `\edef\save{\unexpanded\expandafter{\textandmacro}}` does what you need

Comment: I guess `\let\save\textandmacro` or with LaTeX `\NewCommandCopy{\save}{\textandmacro}`.

Comment: How can you judge coolness without testing? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on whether you need working parameters or not. If not, the `\unexpanded\expandafter{}` approach in [@PhelypeOleinik's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712349/def-and-edef-expansion-for-one-level-not-more#comment1770429_712349) is fine (needs eTeX, but since you're using LuaTeX that's fine):

```
\edef\save{\unexpanded\expandafter{\textandmacro}}
```

Another approach would be just a bunch of `\expandafter` which would work even if you needed parameters for `\save` in `\textandmacro` (though you'd need more `\expandafter`s then):

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\save\expandafter{\textandmacro}
```

Last approach, Knuthian TeX version of the `\unexpanded\expandafter{}` approach:

```
\toks0\expandafter{\textandmacro}
\edef\save{\the\toks0}
```

(on this last one you might want to use groups to keep the assignment to `\toks0` local)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the output should be `sampletext b` (because `\mcr` has changed to `b`). So IMHO `\let` would be fine:

```
\def\mcr{a}
\def\textandmacro{sampletext \mcr} % this content i want to recall later with unexpanded \mcr
\let\save\textandmacro           % so i save it
\def\mcr{b}                        % the macro may change
\def\textandmacro{xy}              % this macro may change, too
%
\save                              % use '\save' here as if to type 'sampletext \mcr'

\tt\meaning\save
\bye
```

[image: sampletext b]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the current content of one macro, use `\let`.

```
\def\textandmacro{sampletext \mcr}
\let\save\textandmacro
\def\mcr{b}
\def\textandmacro{xy}
%
\save % expands to "sampletext \mcr" then further to "sampletext b"
```

You can make `\save` global if you need it to survive the current group.

```
{
  \def\textandmacro{sampletext \mcr}
  \global\let\save\textandmacro
}
% here \save still expands to "sampletext \mcr"
```

For somewhat more complex cases where you want `\save` to contain more than a single macro, you can use `\expandafter`.

```
\def\one{old1}
\def\two{old2}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\save\expandafter{\one\two} % = \def\save{old1\two}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\save\expandafter{\expandafter\one\two} % = \def\save{\one old2}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\save\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\one\two} % = \def\save{old1old2}
```

In classic TeX, even more complex cases tend to call for a complex arrangement of `\expandafter`, `\noexpand`, `\edef` and `\toks`.